# Insert to Access 2007 table with some values from other tables

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am using Access 2007 [normally SQL Server] I'm trying to insert records into a table whereby certain values are ID's from other tables. For example:

insert into table values ((select id from another_table), 1, 'Hello', etc)

This is possible in SQL Server.

I get an error that says, Query must contain at least one table or something...

Anyone know the syntax for this in Access? I've tested all the selects and they all produce the expected results, but when inserted in the above type of statement, I get the error.

I don't want to extract too much data into memory, so I'd prefer to get the above to work, instead of loading the ID's and names as a collection of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you want, but perhaps you are looking at it from the wrong angle?

```
INSERT INTO Table (ID, FK_ID, F2)  
SELECT 1, T2_ID, "Hello"  
FROM  Table2 
WHERE ID=1
```

Comment: I think you want to swap the first two fields of your SELECT, right?

Comment: Why not `SELECT ID, T2_ID, "Hello"`? The hardwired solution means you have to generate the entire SQL statement on the fly each time, whereas using the ID field in the SELECT, you have to supply only the WHERE clause at runtime. Granted, if you parameterized it, you could use the same parameter in both places.

Comment: The OP has `((select id from another_table), 1, 'Hello', etc)` The above shows how this could be written another way to the same end.

Comment: Maybe you're confusing things (for me, if not for anyone else!) by using the literal "1" in both the SELECT and the WHERE?

Comment: I can assure you, I tested. If it makes you happier, I will change the WHERE statement.

Comment: I'm not saying it will produce an incorrect result. I just think it's simpler to have a literal value only in one place, and, as I said, if it were parameterized, that objection would go away.

Comment: The point was to demonstrate a different view to the OP, if I add in too many variations from the original posted example, it is likely to become less clear to the OP.